# echo a one-liner bash script with variables

Tags: bash, echo

I would like to do that:

```
i="1"; echo -e '#!/usr/bin/env bash\nmyprogram -i "input_${i}.txt"'
```

and pipe it to a job scheduler.

However, this doesn't replace the variable i by its value. Instead, I obtain this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
myprogram -i "input_${i}.txt"
```

I played a bit with option -e of echo and with single-/double-quote but could not make it work. For instance, I get this:

```
i="1"; echo -e "#!/usr/bin/env bash\nmyprogram -i \"input_${i}.txt\""
-bash: !/usr/bin/env: event not found
```

My bash version is 4.1.2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
i="1"; echo -e '#!/usr/bin/env bash\nmyprogram -i '"\"input_${i}.txt\""
```

You can `echo` single- and double-quoted strings at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Try also escaping the exclamation mark:

`\!` should be okay, and will not be read as an "event" by bash.

Answer (score 0):

```
i="1"; echo -e '#!/usr/bin/env bash\nmyprogram -i "input_'"${i}"'.txt"'
```

Basically, use single quotes until you need to interpolate, then close the single quotes, open the double quotes, add the interpolation, close the double quotes, reopen single quotes, and finish the string.  In the shell, quotation marks don't delimit a word; they just change the interpretation of the part of a word falling between them.